# Pandas - restructure longitudinal data in a multilevel df to a single-level column

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to restructure a df (6 column) that contains data on 4 different subjects (subject 1 to 4) on 4 different types of tests (test A to D) taken on 4 different days each in it's own column (Day1 to Day4).

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'subject': [1, 2, 2, 3,4,1,1,2,3,2],
                  'test': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','A', 'B', 'C', 'D','B', 'C'],
                  'Day1': ['X1','X2','X3','X4','X5','X6','X7','X8','X9','X10'],
                  'Day2': ['Y1','Y2','Y3','Y4','Y5','Y6','Y7','Y8','Y9','Y10'],
                  'Day3': ['Z1','Z2','Z3','Z4','Z5','Z6','Z7','Z8','Z9','Z10'],
                  'Day4': ['K1','K2','K3','K4','K5','K6','K7','K8','K9','K10']})
```

What my DataFrame currently looks like:

[image]

To analyze my data, I would like to restructure it into a single long format 'flat-spread' - where each subject has only one row containing all the observations.

Desired structure:

[image]

Comment: Indexes (column names and row indexes) must be unique, so this isn't possible with the example data you posted.

For instance, the row with `subject = 2` and `test = C` appears twice, meaning they'd have two different values for each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with the example data you provided since pandas indexes (both column and row labels) cannot contain duplicates. An example of one in your data is `Subject 2` and `test C` -- this combination appears twice, meaning it's impossible to know which values should go along with the corresponding days.

In the event that you had unique column and row labels, you could use a combination of [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'subject': [1, 2, 2, 3,4,1,1,2,3,2],
                  'test': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','A', 'B', 'C', 'D','B', 'C'],
                  'Day1': ['X1','X2','X3','X4','X5','X6','X7','X8','X9','X10'],
                  'Day2': ['Y1','Y2','Y3','Y4','Y5','Y6','Y7','Y8','Y9','Y10'],
                  'Day3': ['Z1','Z2','Z3','Z4','Z5','Z6','Z7','Z8','Z9','Z10'],
                  'Day4': ['K1','K2','K3','K4','K5','K6','K7','K8','K9','K10']})

melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['subject', 'test'])
```

`melted` reshapes the data based on the `id_vars` that are passed to it. It now looks like this:

```
   subject test variable value
0        1    A     Day1    X1
1        2    B     Day1    X2
2        2    C     Day1    X3
3        3    D     Day1    X4
4        4    A     Day1    X5
```

Now you can create a new column containing the values you want to be your column headers. **These must be unique.**

```
melted['col_name'] = 'test' + melted['test'] + '-' + melted['variable']
```

Now `melted` has the appropriate values for what we want to be our headers in the long format:

```
   subject test variable value    col_name
0        1    A     Day1    X1  testA-Day1
1        2    B     Day1    X2  testB-Day1
2        2    C     Day1    X3  testC-Day1
3        3    D     Day1    X4  testD-Day1
4        4    A     Day1    X5  testA-Day1
```

`pivot` gets us the rest of the way, but **will not work** in this case because the headers are not unique (again, the issue with `Subject 2` and `test C`).

```
melted.pivot('subject', columns='col_name', values='value')
```

If, for instance, the `DayN` rows were timestamps, we likely wouldn't be having this issue.

Comment: You're the man, Greg! That's what I was looking for exactly (with very minor edits on the column name).